# Integral of locally integrable function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f ∈ L^1(loc)$, the space of locally integrable functions. Show that for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $g(r) =\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy$ is a continuous function.

I was given a hint to show the result holds for all continuous functions and use this to show the result for a general locally integrable function, close to a continuous one.

First I consider an arbitrary continuous function $h$. I need to show, for $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|r-r_0|<\delta \implies |k(r)-k(r_0)|<\epsilon$ where $k(r)=\int_{B(x,r)}h(y)dy$.

I did the following $$|\int_{B(x,r)}h(y)dy-\int_{B(x,r_0)}h(y)dy|=|(\frac{r}{r_0})^n\int_{B(x,r_0)}h(x+\frac{r}{r_0}(z-x))dz-\int _{B(x,r_0)}h(z)dz|\\=(\frac{r}{r_0})^n|\int_{B(x,r_0)}h(x+\frac{r}{r_0}(z-x))dz-(\frac{r_0}{r})^n\int _{B(x,r_0)}h(z)dz|$$

Now I am trying to use the continuity of $h$ but I cannot figure how to do this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Using Dominated Convergence Theorem $$|g(r+h)-g(r)|\leq \int_{\mathbb R}|\boldsymbol 1_{B(x,r+h)}-\boldsymbol 1_{B(x,r)}||f|\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Comment: @Surb I was supposed to prove it without using this.

Comment: It's strange de work with locally $L^1$ function and not being able to use DCT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the dominated convergence theorem for this.
Note that (using your notation for $k$)
\begin{eqnarray}
|k(r) - k(r_0) | &=& \left|\, \int_{B(x,r)} h(y) \, dy - \int_{B(x,r_0)} h(y) \, dy \,\right|  \\
&=& \left| \, \int_{A(x; r,r_0)} h(y) \, dy \,\right|  \\
&\le&   \int_{A(x; r,r_0)} \left| h(y)\right| \, dy  \le \text{vol}A(x;r,r_0) ||h||_{\infty,B(x,r)}
\end{eqnarray}
where $A(x;r,r_0)$ is the $(n-)$ dimensional 'annulus' with center $x$, inner radius $r_0$ and outer radius $r$. This is assuming $r>r_0$ -- if the reverse inequality applies the same statement holds with $A(x;r_0,r)$ instead.
The volume of $A(x;r, r_0)$ equals $C_1 (r^n- r_0^n)$ for some constant $C_1 = C(n)$.

If $f$ is continuous, then $|f|\le C_2 $ on some ball $B_R(x)$ with $R> \max{\{r, r_0\}}$, so
$$|k(r) - k(r_0)| \le C_1 C_2 |r^n - r_0^n|$$
which tends to $0$ if $r\rightarrow r_0$ due to the continuity of $r\mapsto r^n$.
Can you finish the proof now for $f\in L^1_{\text{ loc}}$?